# Вывод количества элементов с формы в C#

Tags: c#

Как вывести с формы количество элементов в listbox,например button. Сами button создаются динамически при щелчке на него. Нужно найти кол-во именно новосозданных button.

Comment: в C# нет кнопок. Укажите, какую технологию вы используете

Comment: как сделать, чтобы выводилось именно количество button, которые создаются при щелчке на них?

Comment: @prizm: код ваш? Вот при добавлении кнопки и увеличивайте счётчик, делов-то!

Answer (score 2):

Количество элементов -    `int x = this.Controls.Count;`

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать, чтобы выводилось именно количество button, которые создаются при щелчке на них?

Answer (score 1):

VladD прав, если код Ваш самостоятельно и подсчитывайте или как в примере выводите количество кнопок в списке:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        Button btn;
        int x = 0;

        private void yourMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Hello";
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //создание кнопки
            x += 70;
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "b" + x;
            btn.Left = x;
            btn.Top = 100;
            btn.Height = 50;
            btn.Width = 50;
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            //добавляем событие
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(yourMethod);

            //добавляем в коллекцию
            buttons.Add(btn);

            //выводим количество
            label1.Text = buttons.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```